# Filtering for Parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-bootstrap

When using the `$urlMatcherFactory` provider to create new parameter types, is there a way to filter types while encoding/decoding or validating them? I need some "date" parameters, and it seems easiest to just create a custom type that can encode/decode them from the URL, as the built-in "date" type does not use the same date formats I want. I need to do this in a `config` block, as I need to do it before actually defining the states. This means I can only use providers (as far as I know, please correct me if I am wrong).

I found a way to use the date parser service from Angular Bootstrap for decoding the date, by injecting the `uibDateParserProvider` provider then retrieving the service with `$get`, but this does not seem like the best way to go. Also, it seems like the `$filter` provider does not work the same way, as `$filterProvider.$get` returns an array with an injection function or something like that as the 2nd element. This injection function is not the `$filter` service. I have not delved deeply enough into the `angular` source to be able to figure out what it actually is, but would be very interested to find out. I know I could parse the dates out myself, but why do that when there are so many helpful `angular` services to do it for me?

Here is an example of what I am trying to do (uses ES6):

```
angular.module('myModule').config(myStates);

function myStates($filterProvider, $urlMatcherFactoryProvider, $stateProvider, uibDateParserProvider) {
    const decodeDateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd'; // the decoder date format
    const encodeDateFormat = 'MMM dd, yyyy'; // the encoder format, which is different from the decoder format

    $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type('mydate', {
        // encode when switching states, e.g. `$state.go()`
        encode: item => {
            const $filter = $filterProvider.$get(); // returns an array like: ['$filter', filterService] (not sure what the 2nd element is)
            $filter('date')(item, decodeDateFormat); // this is what I ultimately want to do
        },
        // decode from the URL so we can use it as a date
        // this uses a different format from the encoder date format
        decode: item => {
            const uibDateParser = uibDateParserProvider.$get(); // returns the uibDateParser service
            return uibDateParser.parse(item, encodeDateFormat);
        },
        // validate
        is: item => {
            return item == null || angular.isDate(item); // just need to know if it is a date
        },
    });

    $stateProvider.state('myState', {
        url: 'my-path?{someParam:mydate}',
        someParam: null,
    });
}
```

**Is there any way to use services when creating parameter types for the Angular UI Router?** Otherwise, how do I get the `$filter` service from its provider, so I can do the filtering?

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to use the `$filter` service by getting it from the `$injectorProvider` it self, e.g., `$injectorProvider.$get().get('$filter');`.

The following snippet is an example of usage in the config phase.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(function($injectorProvider) {
    var $filter = $injectorProvider.$get().get('$filter');
    console.log($filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
  });
angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That is ridiculously complicated just to get a simple service.

Comment: @trysis of course it's complicated, it's like you were trying to have a beer before you get the age of eighteen :{D but seriously though, you have to use the injector because at the config phase, angulajs can't guarantee that all modules are loaded, so that the only thing that you have at this phase, is a factory. Also, the `$filter` service is a special case, because it require your filters to be registered on the `$filterProvider`, anyways, cheers

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say, but I would not have tried to have a beer before 18, or even 21. I was just trying to say that this seems like a very complicated solution for the situation I am trying to solve. I suppose it does not matter whether it is complicated overall.

Comment: do you have a source for the `$injectorProvider`? I was able to find [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) on the Angular 1 site, but not `$injectorProvider`.

Comment: @trysis There is no source for `$injectorProvider` because there is no injector provider, not a raw provider, is the service factory it self, every service can be injected using a the `Provider` sufix.to get a factory.

Comment: @trysis sorry about the beer joke that was a poor analogy. I mean, it's just because is not a normal situation, it runs a little on how angularjs internals expect the config phase to be, so things like that start becoming complex. Anyways, cheers :{D